# Java regular expression to parse between dates?

Tags: java, regex, logging

I am struggling to come up with a regular expression to parse some logs that are very unstructured but always have a date that begins with the line that needs to be parsed.

An example is `2015-9-20 05:20:22 lots of log data` and then the next date for the next line. So I would basically need to parse everything from the starting date until the next date.

```
2015-9-20 05:20:22 lots of log data 
2015-9-20 05:21:22 lots of new log data
```

Is it possible to parse this using regular expression?

Comment: I'd don't think regular expression is you best choice here, you'd be better parsing the `String` to a `Date` or `LocalDateTime` and using the comparison capabilities (`is/Before/After` or `equals`)

Comment: Your statement of the problem seems to be poor. With the example you've shown, all you need to do is read lines and delete the first 19 characters of each one. Why do you need a regex for that?

Comment: @Gene,sorry for not being clear, there are others things i do after i grab the text in between those lines. Once i get the text i need to run through another iteration and because there are multiple lines in between those dates it poses a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I would basically need to parse everything from the starting date until the next date.

If you want to match lines beggining with one date, or beggining with the following day (startDate + 1 day), you can use it in your pattern as literal text.

Using the dates in your example:

```regex
^(?:2015-9-20|2015-9-21) .*
```

#### Code:

```java
// Instantiate a Date object
Date startDate = new GregorianCalendar(2015, 8, 20).getTime();

// Calculate end date (+1 day)
Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
endDate.setTime(startDate);
endDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // Add 1 day

// format dates the same way logs use
SimpleDateFormat ft = 
    new SimpleDateFormat ("y-M-d");

// Create regex
String datesRegex = "^(?:" + ft.format(startDate) + "|" + ft.format(endDate.getTime()) + ") .*";
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/DMTTIP78201)

---

If you want to get all lines from one date to another, and not only those starting with a given date, you should match with the `.DOTALL` modifier:

```regex
^2015-9-20 .*?(?=^2015-9-21 |\z)
```

#### Code:

```java
// Create regex
String datesRegex = "^" + ft.format(startDate) + " .*?(?=^" + ft.format(endDate.getTime()) + " |\\z)";
// Compile
Pattern.compile(datesRegex, Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/JUS87352)

Comment: This gave me a good idea on how to approach the problem. Thanks

Comment: TBH, I still don't know what you're trying to match.. I added an alternative if you want lines in between

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're reading the file line-by-line, this should work for you:

> ^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (.*)$

Code example:

```
     String line = "2015-9-20 05:20:22 log data" + System.lineSeparator();
     String pattern = "^\\d{4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} (.*)$";

     // Create a Pattern object
     Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

     // Now create matcher object.
     Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

     if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Value after timestamp is: " + m.group(1));
     } else {
        System.out.println("NO MATCH");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexMatches
{
    public static void main( String args[] ){

    String s1 = "2015-9-20 05:20:22 lots of log data";
    String s2 = "2015-9-20 05:21:22 lots of new log data";

    String pattern = "(\\d{4})-(0?\\d|1[0-2])-([012]\\d|3[01]) ([01]?\\d|2[0-4]):([0-5]?\\d):([0-5]?\\d)";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher m = r.matcher(s1); //same for s2
    if(m.find())
         System.out.println("True");
    else
         System.out.println("False");  
   }
}
```

Output: `True`